# What does "make tough labor" means?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

In the sentence "The American automaker is scheduled to make tough labor and production cuts." What does "make tough labor" mean?

Comment: It's the cuts that are tough, not the labor.

Answer (score 1):

In this sentence "tough" is an adjective that is modifying the entire phrase "labor and production cuts". There are labor costs and there are production cuts, and both of those (groups of) cuts are tough.